# Unable to return data from $.post to display using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html content look like this:

```
            <table>
                    <tr>
                          <th>Log1 Column</th>
                          <th>Log2 Column</th>
                          <th>Log3 Column</th>
                    </tr>
            <tbody id="bottomLogTable"></tbody>
            </table>
```

Somehow I'm not getting the return data from $.post in the #bottomLogTable location but firebug says 200 ok, meaning the data returned.

```
        $("#logClick").live("click", function()
        {
              $.post("node2542.txt", function(data)
              {
                    $("#bottomLogTable").append(data); // not display returned data
                    $("#bottomLogTable").html(data); // also not display returned data

              });
        });
```

Any suggestions or ideas to get me going in the right direction in resolving this issue?

Comment: posting to a .txt file? What are the contents of this file?

Comment: That should work, assuming `data` contains table rows.

Comment: I have my tr row information in this file....

Comment: Shouldn't you be using get, rather than post?  You're not sending any data in, are you? Just requesting a text file...

Comment: I see the returned data in post when viewing it from Firebug and even can copy and paste it directly into #bottomLogTable

Comment: Did you check for a cross-domain issue?

Comment: Same problem in IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** if you effectively receive the response but still not working it may be a cross-domain issue. You may try putting your text file in exact same domain as your page to see if it work...

And it may worth mentionning that Live is deprecated in last version of jQuery...

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers
>
> http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: you don't know what version of jQ the OP is using, so this is definitely not an answer...

Comment: when or how are you injecting your element #logClick in the page?

Comment: I think I see the problem. When I put the returned $.post data using in the table id instead of the id of tbody (#bottomLogTable), it works. When looking at the html code. Somehow html or whoever puts a tbody element around the header (th) tags automatically. I"m still not sure why it did not put it in the tbody id of #bottomLogTable element

Comment: There is always a tbody in the DOM when there is at least 1 row... try $('#yourTable > tbody').append(...);